# Track focus events on an iframe that do not have the same origin?

Tags: javascript, iframe

Is it possible to see if an interactive element in an iframe (or iframe itself) receives focus or loses focus (blur)?

I have a modal window with a YouTube player embedded as well as a close button for the modal.

I want to remain the focus state inside the modal as long as the modal is open. 
I want to put the focus on the close button when the last interactive element of the player has lost focus and when the close button has lost focus set the focus back on the first interactive element of the player.

I tried using `contentWindow.document` but I get no access.

https://codepen.io/ingvi/pen/4b91e4632043bead3dade1eb63423970?editors=1010

Comment: I apologize that I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I've been facing a similar issue with cross-origin iframe focus, which I documented on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54953474/tracking-focus-on-cross-origin-iframe/54953475).

Hope it helps!