# Tracking focus on cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, focus

I have a web app with an embedded video within an iframe, typically from a cross-origin source (e.g. YouTube). I currently track focus on `window` for logging purposes. However, since iframes are not children of `window`, when the user clicks into the iframe, `window` blurs, stopping my logs though the user is still viewing the page. How can I track focus to this cross-origin iframe?

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr - you can't track focus on the iframe, at least not directly. But there are other sources of information that can be useful enough.

Since the iframe is cross-origin, that immediately rules out accessing its focus state directly, attaching any event handlers, or posting any messages. However, you can use `document.body.activeElement` to see if the user clicked on the iframe as opposed to another tab/window. With that knowledge, this hack is possible:

```
const handleLeave = () => {
  const { activeElement } = document;
  const iframeIsActiveElement = activeElement && activeElement.tagName === 'IFRAME';

  if (iframeIsActiveElement) {
    // timeout necessary to not blur the iframe too quickly
    setTimeout(() => activeElement.blur(), 0);
    return;
  }

  doBlurStuff();
};

window.addEventListener('blur', handleLeave);
```

So when `window` blurs, we're checking to see if the user clicked on the iframe. If they did, we're going to blur the iframe (the user's action will have already occurred), which returns focus to `document.body`. For unknown reasons (probably either that it happens too quickly, or that we're not explicitly `focus`ing `document.body`), any `window` `focus` handlers don't fire. And since we're `return`ing early, `doBlurStuff` also doesn't fire.

One tradeoff: since we're focus-jacking, this has accessibility and UX concerns. The user will not be able to use keyboard events for the iframe, since it will never be able to hold focus. This tradeoff may not be worth it for many usages.